# How to prevent lagging when destroying a fragment having 4 other fragments inside a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a fragment that has a viewpager, let's call it `fragmentA`. I use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter for this. The problem occurs when I am replacing `fragmentA` with another fragment. For some reason, it causes the app to kind of lag for one or two seconds before actually committing the next fragment. The animations are also not run. I am thinking that Android is destroying the inner fragments before replacing it, and the inner fragments have lists in them which causes the app to lag. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the fragments to your frame then using hide() and show() instead of replacing the fragment each time ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be too memory intensive and could cause memory leaks?

Comment: Probably, I avoid using Fragment transactions, I currently created a Non swipeable viewpager and added my fragments to it instead of using a frame. the viewpager destroys and recreates the fragments depending on the OffScreenPageLimit I set the viewpager too

Comment: Would this be viable even if I have around 30 fragments? I also use dagger so would the presenters, views, models and other objects initialized for each fragment would still be there even if they're hidden?

Comment: Yes they would but in that case I would set an off screen limit of around 2 depending on your needs, that way only 2 fragments on each side will be created you or you can leave it to 1 so 1 fragment on each side will be created then when you scroll away they are destroyed so the viewpager only keeps 3 fragments created at a time

Comment: Yes that would work for the `fragmentA`, the fragment having the viewpager. But I would need to replace fragmentA with other fragments. All in all it would be around 30 fragments. Would the show/hide technique still be viable having in mind that each has presenters, views, and models that are kept in memory while it's hidden?

Comment: you would have 1 viewpager in which you will have all your 30 fragments but what happens is that the viewpager only loads by default the current, previous and next fragment so the view pager only keeps 3 loaded fragments at a time

Answer (score 0):

It all depend on the speed and RAM of the device. The viewpager will have to poulate all its children before displaying on the screen. As a result, lag on some devices